# Tag Question questions

Tags: question-tags

1. Linda read a novel which is written in English, 　　　?
   　 (A) does she　(B) doesn't she　(C) did she　(D) didn't she

The answer is "(c) did she", but why is it (c) and not "(D) didn't she"?

2. These aren't your dictionaries, 　　　?
   　(A) are these　(B) aren't these　(C) are they　(D) aren't they

The answer is "(C) are they", why is it not "(A) are these"?

Comment: 1. Past tense therefore'did' not 'does'. In my view, both C and D are correct. They have different emphasis. 2. 'They' is colloquial, not 'these'. C is correct, the negative D is not appropriate as it requires a positive.

Comment: *Linda read a novel which was written in English, didn't she?* *These aren't your dictionaries, are they? It's a fixed rule to use it* instead of *this* and *that*, and *they* instead of *these* and *those* in tag questions.

Comment: Exam questions may be OT here.

Comment: Then I think the exam gave me the wrong answer on Q1, apparently the answer should be "didn't she."